# Can anyone explain how do we get this output ? (bitwise not)

Tags: java

int x=10;

System.out.println(~x);

//this will print -11

//how to do the calculation manually using complement arithmetic

Comment: I assure you there exists many guides on how `not` works. What part are you having problems understanding?

Comment: how to do the calculation by hand

Comment: And part about that? This is very broad. You need to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Negation operator it will consider ~x= -(10+1), so you will get -11 as the output. Refer some C books you can get more explanation on this

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps you: You can print out the bits of the integer as following. There you can see that a int is represented as a 32-bit value. Explanations about bitwise not operator can be found on the web i guess;

```
    int x = 10;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));  //00000000000000000000000000001010
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(~x)); //11111111111111111111111111110101
    System.out.println(~x); //-11
```